# Sending Nalgebra VectorN between threads

Tags: multithreading, multidimensional-array, rust, linear-algebra

I'm using Nalgebra's `VectorN<f64, N>` type in some single-threaded code which is working well. I'm now trying to multithread various parts of the algorithm, but have run into issues passing `VectorN`s into a `thread::spawn` call. For example, the following code fails to compile:

```
use std::thread;
use nalgebra::{VectorN, DefaultAllocator, DimName};
use nalgebra::allocator::Allocator;

struct Test<N>
where
    N: DimName,
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<f64, N>,
{
    pub field: VectorN<f64, N>,
}

impl<N> Test<N>
where
    N: DimName,
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<f64, N>,
{
    pub fn test(&self) {
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let thing = self.field;

            let thing2 = thing * 2.0;

            thing2
        });

        let res = handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

With this error:

```
error[E0277]: `<nalgebra::base::default_allocator::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::base::allocator::Allocator<f64, N>>::Buffer` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> trajectories/src/path/mod.rs:34:22
   |
34 |         let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `<nalgebra::base::default_allocator::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::base::allocator::Allocator<f64, N>>::Buffer` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<f64, N, nalgebra::base::dimension::U1, <nalgebra::base::default_allocator::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::base::allocator::Allocator<f64, N>>::Buffer>`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not
implemented for `<nalgebra::base::default_allocator::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::base::allocator::Allocator<f64, N>>::Buffer`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `nalgebra::base::matrix::Matrix<f64, N, nalgebra::base::dimension::U1, <nalgebra::base::default_allocator::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::base::allocator::Allocator<f64, N>>::Buffer>`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

I've tried various definitions for `N` and `DefaultAllocator` in the `where` clauses but haven't got far. Various search engines have turned up nothing useful around this issue.

If I replace `VectorN<f64, N>` with `VectorN<f64, U3>` (or any other `U*` type from Nalgebra), the above error goes away. I've read the [Nalgebra generic programming guide](https://www.nalgebra.org/generic_programming/) however that seems out of date and perhaps not what I need; I don't want *complete* genericity, just the ability to use `VectorN` with any size bound. What trait bounds do I need to put on my struct so I can pass `field` into a thread?

Comment: This is very confusing. It seems there is something about `Allocator`'s `Sync` impl, so it only applies to types known to the crate, but I stopped short of going down the rabbit-hole..

Comment: @PeterHall Confusing indeed. I came to the same conclusion looking through the docs; everything _should_ be `Send` and `Sync`, yet somehow it falls over at `Buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab in the dark (based on the error messages given by the compiler) and managed to make this work by adding bounds to `Allocator::Buffer` like this:

```
use nalgebra::allocator::Allocator;

struct Test<N>
where
    N: DimName,
    DefaultAllocator: Allocator<f64, N>,
    <DefaultAllocator as Allocator<f64, N>>::Buffer: Send + Sync,
{
    pub field: VectorN<f64, N>,
}

// snip ...
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to do it and it certainly adds some noise, but it appears to now let me pass Nalgebra constructs into threads.